# python pip install teachable-machine dependency conflicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, teachable-machine

I'm asking a question for my friend, we are working on a `keras` project that requires the use of `teachable machine`. The problem is, `pip install teachable-machine` isn't working for him, and the errors are saying something about dependency conflict.

```
This conflict is caused by:
 teachable-machine 1.1 depends on tensorflow>=2.12 0rc0
 teachable-machine 1.0 depends on tensorflow
 teachable-machine 0.1.2 depends on tensorflow
 teachable-machine 0.1.1 depends on tensorflow
 teachable-machine 0.1.0 depends on tensorflow
 teachable-machine 0.0.2 depends on tensorflow
 teachable-machine 0.0.1 depends on tensorflow
```

[image: teachable-machine install error]

With that in mind, I surfed the internet for solutions but couldn't really find any that helps with this. Since teachable-machine's dependencies are `numpy`, `Pillow`, `tensorflow`, we tried to pip install them all with

```
pip install numpy
pip install Pillow
pip install tensorflow
```

The first 2 was with a message `"Requirement already satisfied: (the package name)"`

But there was an error when it comes to `tensorflow`.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

[image: tensorflow install error]

Comment: Has he tried creating a Python virtual environment for the project?

Comment: Please can you post the complete error message beginning at the word *Traceback* not as links or images but as text.

Comment: Have him uninstall python 3.12 and install python 3.11. Tensorflow does not support 3.12 yet, as it is still relatively new

Comment: you have to use `Python 3.11` or you have to wait for newer version `tensorflow` (which should work with `Python 3.12`) OR you can compile `tensorflow` for `Python 3.12` on your own. On GitHub you can see group list with `tensorflow` compiled (by users) for different devices, different system, different Python versions, etc. https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues BTW: as I remember compiling `tensorflow` on 10-years old computer took me ~7 hours.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments and editing, it's my first time asking a question here. I haven't tried using a python virtual environment as I'm not really familiar with how to use it. I'll also try reinstalling python with the version 3.11. I'll update with you guys if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you everyone. We did it by using `Python 3.11`. @FlyingTeller @furas